# React router v4 inner page (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Try to do this

```
<Route path="/oa/work" component={Work}>
<Route path="/oa/work/addwork" component={AddWork}/>
</Route>
```

My link `<Link className="btn-blue-style" to="/oa/work/addwork">Add new Job</Link>`

When clicking I don't move to **AddWork** page, just stay on **Work** and link changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) to make sure the complete location path is matched.

```
<Route exact path="/oa/work" component={Work}>
<Route exact path="/oa/work/addwork" component={AddWork}/>
```

Your Router should look like this:

```
   <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/oa/work">Work</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/oa/work/addwork">Add Work</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <hr />
            <Route exact path="/oa/work" component={Work} />
            <Route exact path="/oa/work/addwork" component={AddWork} />    
        </div>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong here. That is the way [Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) component (react-router-v4) work.
In your code, you didn't set `exact`:

```
<Route path="/oa/work" component={Work}>
<Route path="/oa/work/addwork" component={AddWork}/>
```

So when when location is `/oa/work/addwork`. `Work` component will be return, because `/oa/work/addwork` contains `/oa/work`.
If you set `exact = true`:

```
<Route exact path="/oa/work" component={Work}>
<Route exact path="/oa/work/addwork" component={AddWork}/>
```

It will return component if the location is matched exactly. In your case, the location is `/oa/work/addwork`, it will return `AddWork`